# Wait for all promises to resolve on a forEach loop

Tags: ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

I've been banging my head against a wall the whole morning. I have the following code:

```js
let fold = [{...},{...},{...}] // fold is an array of objects, abbreviated here for simplicity
let track = []
async function getTracks() {
   fold.forEach(async (f, index) => {
      let track = {};
      track.name = f.name;
      track.start = f.start;
      await storageRef
         .child(foldId + "/" + f.filename)
         .getDownloadURL()
         .then((url) => {
             console.log(url); // *
             track.src = url;
         });
      await tracks.push(track);
   });
}
getTracks().then(console.log(tracks)); // **
```

I expect to get an array of objects in `track`, which should be only printed to the console when the forEach loop finishes. Instead, I am getting the following output:

```
Array []
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/musicfolds.appspot.com/o/L69IkyFyaLHu2KkxgrdL%2F1589059357106
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/musicfolds.appspot.com/o/L69IkyFyaLHu2KkxgrdL%2F1589059425650
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/musicfolds.appspot.com/o/L69IkyFyaLHu2KkxgrdL%2F1589553387295
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/musicfolds.appspot.com/o/L69IkyFyaLHu2KkxgrdL%2F1589059596340
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/musicfolds.appspot.com/o/L69IkyFyaLHu2KkxgrdL%2F1589570099464
```

As you see, the array is printed to the console from the `.then` instruction at ** before the forEach resolves the urls (which get printed in order at *, but **after** the `.then`!
Incidentally, the array prints in a strange way: it appears empty, but when clicking on it (I'm on firefox in case that matters), it shows the results as expected.

How can I make my forEach loop wait until the urls return, so I can populate my array with actual values?

Thanks!!!

Comment: `.forEach()` is not promise aware.  Change to a regular `for` loop and then the `await` will actually pause the loop.  Or, if you want to run in parallel, use `await Promise.all(fold.map(...))` and return a promise from within the `.map()` callback.

Comment: Right, I knew there was something regarding that. Could you give me a simple example of returning a promise from within the `.map()` callback? Thanks!

Comment: @metronomme "*returning a promise*" is just what your `async (f, index) => {` callback already does.